# Using TCPDF to output full image background in LANDSCAPE view

Tags: php, tcpdf

I just discovered TCPDF i was hoping to use it to output a certificate in pdf format. i'm current using the example 51 in the master pdf folder which shows how to output a full page image background in PORTRAIT view, however i'm trying to create a full page image backfround in LANDSCAPE. i've tried creating a new page and changing the orientation from `P` for `PORTRAIT` to `L` for `LANDSCAPE` which works fine. i went further to create the image background in adobe illustartor with A4 landscape page settings. On the `$pdf->image()` i have googled the parameters

`Image( $file, $x = '', $y = '', $w = 0, $h = 0, $type = '', $link = '', $align = '', $resize = false, $dpi = 300, $palign = '', $ismask = false, $imgmask = false, $border = 0, $fitbox = false, $hidden = false, $fitonpage = false, $alt = false, $altimgs = array() )`

i have tried setting `resize` to `true`, `fitonpage` to `true` but the image just disappears and is not in the output pdf. i have also tried playing with the width and height but no luck.

This is the output i get

**Current output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

How can i achieve the desired output pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Simple in the image syntax swap the width & height elements.

```
$this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 297, 210, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to convert into landscape mode:

1. Go to /config of tcpdf
2. Edit tcpdf_config.php
3. Replace define `('PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION', 'P');` with define `('PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION', 'L');`